# Mux Audio and Video in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, webm, matroska

I'm looking for a way to join separate audio and video streams into a single container.

Specifically I have VP8 video (webm container) and 16-bit PCM audio (wav container), which I'd like to combine into a Matroska container.

So far I can achieve this by saving the streams to files, and calling ffmpeg.exe by using the Process API which produces the result I need, but I'd prefer a solution that doesn't rely on saving the intermediate files to disk or requiring the ffmpeg.exe to be on the server. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a managed Matroska/WebM library, or at least a managed wrapper to some native library if you want to avoid the additional process. I'm not aware of any that exist/are up-to-date. I started writing one a few years ago but never completed it.

On launching the process, it's not actually necessary to "save files to disk", as you can use a named pipe, which "looks like a file on disk", but is in fact just an interface to some in-memory value - so you can share the memory directly with ffmpeg/mkvmerge, by passing them the name of the pipe in place of the regular filename. Can't help with not requiring the binary on the server though - other than just packaging it with your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll experiment with using named pipes, that would solve that requirement nicely. If I don't get an answer on an alternative to the ffmpeg.exe I'll mark this as accepted.